# Intersection of two regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider two function $f,g$ that zero is their regular point. We have
$$
\text{if }\  p \in f^{−1}(0)∩g^{−1}(0),\ \text{ then }\ \dim(\operatorname{span}(\nabla f(p),\nabla g(p)))=2.
$$
I want to show that $f^{−1}(0)∩g^{−1}(0)$ is regular curve with definition:

> **Definition.** Differentiable curve is a subset $C$ of $X$ where every point of $C$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $C\cap U$ is diffeomorphic to an interval of the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\nabla f$ is the direction of maximal change, and you're dealing with a level set of functions $f,g$, you can see that there is no change at all of $f,g$ along these regular surfaces. Thus the tangent vectors are perpendicular to the gradient, as we know from vector calculus. So associated to the gradient vector is a perpendicular plane - the tangent plane of the surface. The intersection of these planes is a line, this is the tangent line for your curve. Show that this is a smooth vector field and then use the basic existence theory of ODEs to conclude it can be integrated to a path with the required diffeomorphism.